# Calling Asynctask in a quick succession

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an application based on GCM which sends data to phone in a quick succession.I am receiving it through broadcast receiver and do action in ASYNCTASK according to parameters received.

My question is that Suppose -- I have called asynctask first time, It did not even reached to doinbackground method and it has been called second time does the first Asynctask would be completed?

Comment: Couldn't you simply check by prolonging an async task with a timed wait and logging a bit to see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on Android version. Quoting documentation:

> **Order of execution**
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks **were executed serially** on a
>   single background thread. Starting **with DONUT, this was changed to a
>   pool of threads** allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel.
>   **Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread** to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html